# Downloaded file is corrupted

Tags: elixir

I am trying to download an image using Dropbox URL in elixir with the following code:

```
%HTTPoison.Response{body: body} = HTTPoison.get!("https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxot6tgw21mthg8/WeVnWhite-1.JPG")
File.write!("image.jpg", body)
```

The file is created successfully with File.write!/2. But when I try to open it, it says the file is corrupted and the size of the file is also different from the original size.

Answer (score 2):

You are downloading Dropbox's [HTML presentation page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxot6tgw21mthg8/WeVnWhite-1.JPG) and saving it as a `jpeg`:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxot6tgw21mthg8/WeVnWhite-1.JPG
```

When you open the file it is not encoded as a JPEG properly because the contents are probably HTML.

The actual image file link you want is [here](https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAVbXWztTiaGBvbN9xqj45gyFxFW5mWFPViVRMhUliZNQ/12/182502757/jpeg/32x32/3/1512439200/0/2/WeVnWhite-1.JPG/ELW71YoBGOvEAiAHKAc/9MJyVOom1Qyql6ewIOrAZsfC6JAzz2BaPAdgIgJvS7o):

```
https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAVbXWztTiaGBvbN9xqj45gyFxFW5mWFPViVRMhUliZNQ/12/182502757/jpeg/32x32/3/1512439200/0/2/WeVnWhite-1.JPG/ELW71YoBGOvEAiAHKAc/9MJyVOom1Qyql6ewIOrAZsfC6JAzz2BaPAdgIgJvS7o
```

Your code will work if you use the correct link.